# geocoding with google maps and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

They are severals geocoding gem ou there at [gems on ruby toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/geocoding___maps.html), maybe more...

I work with the latest version of rails 3.1 (still rc4)

I need to put markers on a map (google) based on addresses

I need to find all markers close to one given location

I need also to find all markers located in one given country

Which gem(s) do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use [Gmaps4Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) to compute automaticaly latitude and longitude in my model

and I'll use [gmap3](http://gmap3.net/) to build the map, a jQuery plugin.

another solution is geocoder, see Ryan Bates' [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder)

this jQuery widget is also very nice [jquery-addresspicker](https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker)

Answer (score 1):

To filter markers, use [Geokit](https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3) for Rails 3.

To geocode and display markers, I definitely recommend my gem [Gmaps4Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to display markers without any gems, just javascript

https://gist.github.com/1017434